# Updating the Compiler for the GPS Community Edition 2019 IDE

Tags: linux, ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I've recently started working on a project that requires my complier to be above GNAT 4.8.5 - When I go to: Help > About

[image]

You can see that the version I'm using is 4.8.5

[image]

Also, when I run the gnatls -v command, I can see this...

```
[parallels@localhost ~]$ gnatls -v

GNATLS 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
Copyright (C) 1997-2013, Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Source Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/adainclude/


Object Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/adalib/


Project Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/gnat
   /usr/share/gpr
   /usr/lib/gnat

[parallels@localhost ~]$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,ada
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC) 
[parallels@localhost ~]$
```

Please could someone be able to tell me how to update my GNAT compiler? Also, I'm using the Centos 7 Operating System.

Thank you,

Lloyd

Comment: ? Have you got a manually installed "gcc 7.3.0" in /usr/local/ ? Please edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61632284/edit ... to show available gcc -7.3.0 executable's. .... Images https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to install a compiler, you already have 3 (at least):

- gcc 4.8.5 (the system compiler) in `/usr/bin`
- gcc 7.3.0 (that you just built) in `/usr/local/bin`
- gcc 8.3.1 (from GNAT CE 2019) in `/home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/bin`

*Your* `PATH` determines which GCC you pick up when you say just `gcc`, and which GNATLS you pick up when you say just `gnatls`, .. etc.

According to a previous post, your `PATH` is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/parallels/.local/bin:/home/parallels/bin/home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/bin/home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/bin
```

so when you say just `gcc` the system looks at the first entry in the `PATH` (which is colon-separated) and .. there it is! so it executes that.

If you'd built your 7.3.0 GCC with Ada support, it would have found gnatls in the same place. I have a very strong suspicion that you didn't, so when you say just `gnatls` the system looks in `/usr/local/bin` - no luck - then in `/usr/local/sbin` - no luck - then in `/usr/bin` - whoopee! but that's the 4.8.5 GCC that you don't want.

Looking again at your `PATH`, the last part is mangled - you've added `/home/parallels/bin` and `/home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/bin` (twice) without including the colon separators, resulting in a nonexistent path. (`/home/parallels/bin` may well have been added by the system - I assume that `/home/parallels` is your home directory).

What you need to do is to make sure that you pick up the compiler that came with GNAT CE 2019 by putting its location **first** in your `PATH`. One way of doing this is by editing your shell startup files.

I don't know how CENTOS sets accounts up, and I don't know what your shell is. Assuming it's `bash` (type `ps -p $$`, should come back with `bash` or perhaps `-bash`; anything else, I can't help), you need to edit one of the shell startup files - I'm a little unclear about this, but I think it'll be `~/.bashrc` (`~` is shorthand for your home directory); see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) for the gory details. Find the last mention of `PATH` and immediately after that line insert

```
export PATH=/home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/bin:$PATH
```

Open a new terminal window and say e.g. `gnatls -v` - you should pick up the GNAT CE 2019 one.

Comment: Just wanted to comment here that this doesn't always work in every linux environment by itself.  We had a redhat environment where setting the path alone did not fully work.  Additionally we had to adjust the toolchain settings (usually under the build menu).  The dialog there had two paths to also modify compiler path and tools path, in addition to a checkbox to allow for multiple toolchains that needed to be checked to set those.  I don't know why our environment required that, but might be something to keep in your back pocket.

Comment: Cheers @Jere, thank you for the heads up. This is something I will keep in mind.

Comment: Hi @Simon Wright, thank you very much for your detailed awser. This has helped me resolve the issue, I have changed the PATH and updated the complier. When I go to: Help > About within CE 2019 I now see this GPS 19.1 (20190106) hosted on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu GNAT Community 2019 (20190517-83) the GNAT Programming Studio (c) 2001-2019 AdaCore Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only way I know of updating GNAT GPS CE from AdaCore is downloading the new one, installing it and then deleting the old one.

Another thing is to upgrade the gnat-gps that some systems had in ther repositories