# Weird error when compiling 32-bit programs with GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, 32bit-64bit, gnat-gps

When I try to compile a simple 32-bit C program using GCC on 64-bit Linux, I get the following message:

```
[teo.samarzija@teos-acer-laptop debug]$ gcc -m32 -o program program.c
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/32/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/32/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/32/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/32/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/32/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/32/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/32/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/32/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/crtbegin.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1/crtend.o' is incompatible with i386 output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do?

Comment: Looks like you have only the 64bit version of GCC

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? How and from where did you install GCC? If you compiled GCC from source, how did you configure it?

Comment: @Ruslan, I got GCC with the GNAT Community IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [another GPS-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61632284/673852), it seems that GPS comes with GCC compiled without support for multilib. If you run `gcc -v`, you'll notice the `--disable-multilib` option mentioned in the output.

I suppose you're out of luck then. You'll either have to build GCC yourself, or install it from some other source unrelated to GPS: e.g. from the repositories of your Linux distribution. Then you'll have to somehow tell GPS to use this other version of GCC.

Comment: Thanks! I compiled GCC 9.3.0 from source and now it works fine.

Comment: By the way, @Ruslan, do you happen to know how I can tell GPS to use a different C and C++ compiler?

Comment: @FlatAssembler no, I've never used GPS.